# C linked list push function, just checking if this is correct

Tags: c, list, pointers, linked-list, stack

So I'm just wondering if this push function, which pushes a new value to the top a linked list stack is correct

```
void push(node** hd, int v){
node temp;
temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
temp -> val = v;
temp -> next = *hd;
*hd = temp;
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Also I'm wondering how I would make a pop function, to pop the most recently pushed value off of the stack.

The struct code looks like this by the way...

```
typedef struct nodeStruct
{
int val;
struct nodeStruct* next;
}node;

typedef node* list;
```

Comment: It definitely looks like it has problems.  SUGGESTION: why not compile and run it under the debugger?

Comment: I don't know how to use my gdb debugger, as I am short on time to finish this I'll definitely learn it for the future.. :\ If the problem is obvious I would like to just know. This is my first time using Linked Lists, and I'm not so great with pointers in just C.

Comment: Your edit actually made things worse. Please reread the answer by @William Morris. (and I agree: typedeffing pointers only increases confusion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont define pointer types. They are confusing.  Define a normal type and dereference it explicitly.  Here is what you were trying to do without the pointer types.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct nodeStruct
{
    int val;
    struct nodeStruct *next;
} node;

static void push(node **head, int v)
{
    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->val = v;
    temp->next = *head;
    *head = temp;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    (void) argv;
    (void) argc;
    node *list = NULL;

    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        push(&list, i);
    }
    for(node *l = list; l != NULL; l = l->next) {
        printf("%d ", l->val);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you should check for failure of `malloc`. In other words, `malloc` can return NULL, which should be handled - left to you.

Comment: For the malloc wasn't I doing node * temp = (*node)malloc(sizeof(node)); ?

Comment: is the problem that it should be node temp instead of list temp, and then remove the (list) in front of malloc?

Comment: The problem stemmed from your use of a typedef'd pointer (`typedef node* list;`).  Just don't do it.

Comment: Sorry I'm just a bit confused on which lists in the code I should just replace with node, and which I should replace with node*.

Comment: I did, but then I'm left with a bunch of lists, do I change them to node* or node?

Comment: Anything that was of type `list` becomes a `node *`